# Exception in accessing the primary key

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables in program

```
        @Entity
        @Table(name="managerlog")
        public class Manager {

        private Integer id;

        private Address address;
        @Id
        @Column(name="id")
        @GeneratedValue
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }
        @OneToOne(mappedBy="mng")
        public Address getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public void setAddress(Address address) {
            this.address = address;
        }


        }
```

Address pojo class

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Address")

    public class Address {

        private Integer id;
        private String locality;
        private Manager mng;

        public Address()
        {

        }
        public Address(String locality) {

            this.locality = locality;
        }
        public Address(Integer id,String locality) {
            this.id=id;
            this.locality = locality;
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name="id")

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        @Column(name="locality")
        public String getLocality() {
            return locality;
        }

        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="MID")

        public Manager getMng() {
            return mng;
        }
        public void setLocality(String locality) {
            this.locality = locality;
        }
        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public void setMng(Manager mng) {
            this.mng = mng;
        }


    }
```

Address table in db is Manager(id,locality,mid)
Problem is i want to access address id based on mid with hibernate query like
    Query qry=session.createQuery(" address.id From Address address where  address.mid=:MID");
and i set the parameter .. giving  me error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.NodeTraverser.traverseDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:63)

..
Here I know the way of getting Manager class ..from that class getting address.. but if i have MID(foreign key) ..can't I get the address.id(primary key).. 
 **Can anyOne explain me ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that the Address class doesn't have the property mid, bacause mid is just  the column of the your database structure. If you want to get the address for that manager, you have to change the query in this way:

```
Query qry=session.createQuery(" address.id From Address address where address.mid.id=:MID");
```

in this case you can set the manager identificator and all should works